# Craftsman 42" snowblower pulley removal part 47026

Tags: small-engine, snowblower, craftsman

I have to put in a new gear but I can't remove the pulley from the back to remove the gear. Tried using a 3 arm pulley puller with no luck. Do they make a tool for this? Pulley part is 47026. Thanks, Tom

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you post up a picture? I think it would really help us help you. You can edit it into the question

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as though the main screw and washer comes off from the shaft, then you can just pull it off. It is probably splined. If you apply a little PB Blaster on it and let it sit for a half hour, then put two long flat tip screw drivers, one on top, one bottom pointing in opposite directions. With this setup, just gently pry back and forth and the pulley should pop off. It should not be pressed on, so should come off with a little bit of maneuvering.

Comment: I sprayed it already and tried using a 3 ton gear puller with no luck. I think they end up rusting right to the shaft. I can't get behind the pulley. I'll add a picture tonight when I get home from work.